# Creating a Filter Function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working through a series of tests to learn JavaScript. I recently made a forEach and map function that looks like this:

```
// **** FOR EACH ****

function forEach(inputArray, iteratingFunction){
    for(var i =0; i < inputArray.length; i++){
        iteratingFunction(inputArray[i]);
    }
}

// **** MAP FUNCTION ****

function map(inputArray, inputFunction){
    var newMapArray = [];
    forEach(inputArray, function(element){
        newMapArray.push(inputFunction(element));
    });
    return newMapArray;
}
```

Now I have to make a filter function. It takes an array and an inputFunction. The `input` or `iteratingFunction` returns boolean values. All true values should be added to a new array.

I am currently passing all the specs with this version of the filter function:

```
// **** FILTER FUNCTION ****

function filter(array, itfunction){
  var newArray = [];
  map(array, function(item){
    if(itfunction(item)){
      newArray.push(item);
    }
  });
  return newArray;
}
```

I don't feel like this is optimal though because map should be returning a new array, and I am pushing items into a new array that I created within the filter function.  I could really use the forEach() function and get the same exact result.  I don't feel like I am using the map function properly here.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to better implement the map function so I don't have to instantiate and create a new array in my filter function? I'd rather try to get my map function to do all the work, since that's its current extra functionality over the forEach function.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make sense to me to use a function like `map` for `filter`. Unless you want to iterate over the array twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement `forEach`, `map`, and `filter` in terms of `reduce`, so you should have probably started with `reduce` first.

```
function reduce(array, iterator, accumulator) {
  var index = -1,
      length = array.length;

  if (arguments.length == 2 && length) {
    accumulator = array[++index];
  }
  while (++index < length) {
    accumulator = iterator(accumulator, array[index], index, array);
  }
  return accumulator;
} // modified version of lodash's reduce
```

Now we can implement `filter` (acc is short for accumulator)

```
function filter(array, tester) {
  return reduce(array, function(acc, value, index){
      if (tester(value, index)) {
          return acc.concat([value]);
      }
      else {
          return array;
      }
  }, []);
}
```

---

Also map and forEach for fun:

```
function map(array, mapper){
    return reduce(array, function(acc, item, index){
        return acc.concat([mapper(item, index)]);
    }, []);
}
```

```
function forEach(array, handler){
    reduce(array, function(acc, item, index){
        handler(item, index);
    }, undefined);
}
```

---

Note: these are purist implementations; you could replace `return acc.concat([x])` with `acc.push(x); return acc;` for slightly better performance at the cost of impure code.